# Finding linked mailboxes

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2007

I have an Exchange 2007 environment in a resource forest scenario with linked mailboxes, which are linked to AD accounts in the customer's domain.

The problem is that some users are unable to view their calendar, out of office, and some are unable to open outlook after they have been updated to 2010, so a couple of things must be done to ensure they are setup correctly, one of them is to ensure the mailbox is linked to the resource forest

Is it possible to run a powershell script to find linked accounts from a list using the Get-Mailbox command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the basic list:

get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails LinkedMailbox

Then you can manipulate the results as required.

Comment: Wow, Sembee, there's a name I haven't noticed online in ages, but immediately recognize. Welcome to ServerFault.